# How do I re-render a component with the same value using hooks?

Tags: react-hooks

I have a component that list the dates of documents that have been verified. When I "verify" a new document I want the component with the list of dates to update, however I'm using the same docID that the component originally rendered off of.
The following works to originally display the component and the "verify" button works to update the DB. However the button does not update the list of dates in my component since the MemberDocID remains the same.

```
dataR.memberDocsID.map(({ CustID, Age, FirstName, MemberID, LastName, Step, SignedDate, MemberDocID}) => (
setrMemberID(MemberID),
setvMemberDocID(MemberDocID),
date = new Date(SignedDate),
  <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
    <Card.Body  >
      <Card.Title>{FirstName} {LastName}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        <b>Waiver</b>
        <p>{Step}</p>
        <b>Signed date</b>
        <p>{date.toLocaleString('en-US')}</p>
        <Button size="sm" variant="info" onClick={() => {
          setUserDocList({
            rMemberDocID: MemberDocID,
            rUserID: nUserID
          });
          setvMemberDocID(MemberDocID);

        }} >Verify </Button>

      </Card.Text>

    </Card.Body>
  </Card>

)
)
}
```

With

```
const [vMemberDocID, setvMemberDocID] = useState(null)
```

I tried to see if I could get it to update it with the same value by doing the following but I get a : "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

```
dataR.memberDocsID.map(({ CustID, Age, FirstName, MemberID, LastName, Step, SignedDate, MemberDocID}) => (
setrMemberID(MemberID),
setvMemberDocList({
  vMemberDocID: MemberDocID
}),
date = new Date(SignedDate),
  <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
    <Card.Body  >
      <Card.Title>{FirstName} {LastName}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        <b>Waiver</b>
        <p>{Step}</p>
        <b>Signed date</b>
        <p>{date.toLocaleString('en-US')}</p>
        <Button size="sm" variant="info" onClick={() => {
          setUserDocList({
            rMemberDocID: MemberDocID,
            rUserID: nUserID
          });

          setvMemberDocList({
            vMemberDocID: MemberDocID,
            vMemberDocIDTrig: vMemberDocList.vMemberDocIDTrig + 1

        }); }} >Verify </Button>

      </Card.Text>

    </Card.Body>
  </Card>

)
)
}
```

with:

```
    const [vMemberDocList, setvMemberDocList] = useState({
      vMemberDocIDTrig: 0,
      vMemberDocID: null
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this was the best solution but it worked. I created a state to hold a value that I passed over to graphql to update a field in my graphql query but one that was worthless in a sense that when it hit my api, I did not use it. However, because the field was updated it allowed graphql to hit the api again and thus re-reload my component.

```
    const [placeHoldervMemberDocID, setplaceHoldervMemberDocID] = useState
    ({
      holderrvMemberDocID: null,
      holdervMemberDocIDTrig: 0})

    const [vMemberDocID, setvMemberDocID] = useState(placeHoldervMemberDocID.holderrvMemberDocID)
```

```
   const { loading: loadingDU, data: dataVD } = useQuery(View_Doc_Usage , {
   variables: {
     memberDocID: parseInt(vMemberDocID,10),
     userID: placeHoldervMemberDocID.holdervMemberDocIDTrig
   },
 }
 );
```

```
dataR.memberDocsID.map(({ CustID, Age, FirstName, MemberID, LastName, Step, SignedDate, MemberDocID}) => (
setrMemberID(MemberID),
setvMemberDocID(MemberDocID),
date = new Date(SignedDate),
  <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
    <Card.Body  >
      <Card.Title>{FirstName} {LastName}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        <b>Waiver</b>
        <p>{Step}</p>
        <b>Signed date</b>
        <p>{date.toLocaleString('en-US')}</p>
        <Button size="sm" variant="info" onClick={() => {
          setUserDocList({
            rMemberDocID: MemberDocID,
            rUserID: nUserID
          });

          setplaceHoldervMemberDocID({
            holderrvMemberDocID: MemberDocID,
            holdervMemberDocIDTrig: placeHoldervMemberDocID.holdervMemberDocIDTrig +1
          });

        }} >Verify </Button>

      </Card.Text>

    </Card.Body>
  </Card>

)
)
}
```